# Agregar múltiples objetos a un estado en React utilizando useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de comercio electrónico utilizando React y estoy teniendo dificultades para agregar múltiples objetos a un estado utilizando el hook useState y useContext. En mi caso, tengo un estado llamado *select* que es un array de objetos. Mi objetivo es agregar varios productos seleccionados al carrito de compras a través del contexto utilizando la función `addProductToCart` proporcionada por el contexto `CartContext`.

Sin embargo, actualmente solo se almacena el último objeto del array en el carrito de compras, en lugar de todos los objetos seleccionados. Aquí está el código relevante:

```
const SetupPage = ({ products }) => {
    const { addProductToCart } = useContext(CartContext);
    const [select, setSelect] = useState([]);

    // falta agregar items del select en el carrito de compras
    const onAddProduct = () => {
        const filteredProducts = select.filter(
            (product) => product.inStock > 0
        );

        filteredProducts.map((product) => {
            let priceWithDiscount =
                product.price - product.price * (product.discount / 100);

            let tempCartProduct = {
                id: product.id,
                description: product.description,
                image: product.images,
                price: product.discount > 0 ? priceWithDiscount : product.price,
                slug: product.slug,
                title: product.title,
                inStock: product.inStock,
                discount: product.discount,
                quantity: 1,
            };

            addProductToCart(tempCartProduct);
        });

    };
    
    return (
        // JSX del componente...
    )
};
```

La función `addProductToCart` (solo estoy mostrando un ejemplo de todo lo que tiene el CartProvider):

```
const CART_INITIAL_STATE = {
    isLoaded: false,
    cart: [],
    numberOfItems: 0,
    subTotal: 0,
    tax: 0,
    total: 0,
    shippingAddress: undefined,
};

const addProductToCart = (product) => {
        const productInCart = state.cart.some((p) => p.id === product.id);
        if (!productInCart)
            return dispatch({
                type: "[Cart] - Update products in cart",
                payload: [...state.cart, product],
            });

        // Acumular
        const updatedProducts = state.cart.map((p) => {
            if (p.id !== product.id) return p;

            // Actualizar la cantidad
            p.quantity = product.quantity;
            return p;
        });

        dispatch({
            type: "[Cart] - Update products in cart",
            payload: updatedProducts,
        });
    };
```

He intentado iterar sobre el arreglo *filteredProducts* y llamar a *addProductToCart* dentro de un `.map()` para agregar cada producto al carrito de compras. Sin embargo, esto solo da como resultado que se almacene el último producto del arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias probar sacar el `addProductToCart(tempCartProduct)` fuera del map. Algo así:

```javascript
const prods = filteredProducts.map((product) => {
    let priceWithDiscount =
    product.price - product.price * (product.discount / 100);

    let tempCartProduct = {
        id: product.id,
        description: product.description,
        image: product.images,
        price: product.discount > 0 ? priceWithDiscount : product.price,
        slug: product.slug,
        title: product.title,
        inStock: product.inStock,
        discount: product.discount,
        quantity: 1,
    };

    return tempCartProduct 
});

addProductToCart(prods);
```

La idea sería mapear la lista de productos en una lista de objetos `tempCartProduct` con el formato que quieres y que esa lista sea la que se agrega con la función `addProductToCart`.